# Gurgling drains

Tags: drainage

Why does my toilet and bath tub drain gurgle when the upstairs neighbors flush the toilet. The toilet gurgling has gotten more louder and forceful over the past couple of weeks.

Comment: a blockage is coming

Comment: If there is any sort of building management, ask them to take a look at it. It sounds like the issue is most likely in some common/shared plumbing portion for which neither you nor the upstairs neighbor would be responsible, even if you each own a condo/townhouse. If it's a rental, it's _definitely_ the landlord's responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the vent has some partial blockage and as the water drops through the drain it needs to disperse air more than the vent can allow. I have seen leaves, twigs and even small animals blocking a vent pipe.
You said "upstairs neighbors"  If you live in an apartment or condo building the management company needs to be notified.